# Angular 6 functions that consumes Observable from HTTP GET returns before building the Data

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, reactivex

I am trying to read data from a REST endpoint. After reading data and I want to construct a List of instances and return the list.

But since `HTTP` `GET` function returns a `Observable` method always returns and empty list before constructing it from response.

Here is my code:

```
 public getUsers() {
    let responseValue = this.http.get(this.utils.provideserviceURL('http://test.com/users'));

    responseValue.toPromise()
    .then(result => {
      let usersList: User[] = [];
      let jsonResult = result.json();
      for (let temp of jsonResult) {
        let tempUser = new User(jsonResult.id, jsonResult.username, jsonResult.password, jsonResult.firstName, jsonResult.lastName);
        usersList.push(tempUser);
      }
      console.log(usersList);
      return usersList;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Error while fetching Users
      console.log('Error');
    });

  }
```

Here the function returns `undefined` and then prints the console with the proper data.

I am not fully aware of proper way to use the `toPromise()`. Please point me to the post if its already been discussed and make this question as duplicate.

Comment: If the information on the following link is true, toPromise is deprecated. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html
However, I would expect what you did to work. I'd suggest you look into the basics of Observables, and try to solve your problem by subscribing to the http response. Angular 6 seems to be working heavily with Observables, and if you can change the code as you wish, I think looking into Observables is a good investment.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in JavaScript doesn’t wait until the response come back. Doesn’t make sense that you return something in the behavior after the response

I think you should save your list in an attribute, and use that in your component or where you want to use it.

```
public users: Users = undefined

public getUsers() {
    let responseValue = this.http.get(this.utils.provideserviceURL('http://test.com/users'));

    responseValue.toPromise()
    .then(result => {
      let usersList: User[] = [];
      let jsonResult = result.json();
      for (let temp of jsonResult) {
        let tempUser = new User(jsonResult.id, jsonResult.username, jsonResult.password, jsonResult.firstName, jsonResult.lastName);
        usersList.push(tempUser);
      }
      console.log(usersList);
      this.users = usersList;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Error while fetching Users
      console.log('Error');
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it (I saw toPromise is depreciated),

```
constructor(private dataservice: DataService){}

myEmail: string = '';
myID: number = 0;

ngOnInit(){
this.dataservice.getMe()
.subscribe((data: WhoAmI) => {
  this.myEmail = data.Contacts.find(x=>x.ContactTypeName == "Email").ContactValue;
  this.myID = data.ID;
});
```